# jQuery: 100% height of THIS div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use **.height()** to get height from **.post** and apply it to **.left**, each **.post** has different heights so I need to use **this()** I think, but can't find the solution... My jQuery only snaps the height from the first **.post**.

```
<div class="object">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="left">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $height = $('.object .post').height();
    $final = $height-53
    $('.object .post .left').css({
        height: $final
    });
});
```

Comment: You are giving the answer yourself: You have to define from the perspective of each specific `.left` element how you get the height of the corresponding `.post`. You are currently selecting all `.post` divs, and `.height()` will get the height of the first matched element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.left').height(function() {
        return $(this).parent().height() - 53;
    });
});
```

This will set the height of each `.left` div to its corresponding parent `.post` minus 53px.

Comment: Works as a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**or just use css**

```
.post{position:relative}
.left{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%}
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/rzFhL/